# Python Multiplying Integers inside "print()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiplication

So I have the code (Relevant code):

```
print("You have chosen to bet on the even numbers")
valin = input("How much would you like to bet?: ")
print("If it lands on an even number, you win", valin*2)
```

What I want it to do is print the value of valin multiplied by 2, but have no idea how to do that! How ?

Comment: What did you try? What happened when you tried it? What did you want to happen? Why do you think that happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the input string to an integer with `int`:

```
valin = int(input("How much would you like to bet?: "))
```

then proceed as before.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that the result of [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) will be a `str`, not an `int`, and multiplication has a different meaning for strings.  Here is an example:

```
>>> valin = input("How much would you like to bet?: ")
How much would you like to bet?: 20
>>> type(valin)      # valin is a string!
<type 'str'>
>>> valin * 2        # multiplication will concatenate the string to itself
'2020'
>>> int(valin) * 2   # first convert it to an int, then multiply
40
```

You need to do as larsmans suggested, and convert it to an `int` before the multiplication.  Here is a version with some extra validation:

```
print("You have chosen to bet on the even numbers")
while True:
    try:
        valin = int(input("How much would you like to bet?: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input, please enter an integer")
print("If it lands on an even number, you win", valin*2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Python String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
print("If it lands on an even number, you win %d" % (int(valin) * 2))
```

**Edit:** You might want to do some input validation to make sure that what you get from `input` is an integer, or can be parsed as an integer, and otherwise ask again.

**Edit 2:** If the comment from larsmans is correct, you need to parse the input to an `int`. Fixed above.

Comment: The OP seems to be using Python 3, where `input` always returns a string (like `raw_input` in Python 2).

Comment: I would suggest using the python-3 preferred string formatting method: `"If it lands on an even number, you win {}".format(int(valid) * 2)`. Comes to the same thing in the end though.

Answer (score 0):

print("If it lands on an even number, you win %d" % valin*2)

Comment: The issue is `valin` being `str` instead of `int` as others have pointed out. Also `%` has precedence over `*`. You need to put `valin*2` inside `()`.